# any property toString() method gives StackOverflowError on JavaFX

Tags: java, properties, javafx-8, stack-overflow, tostring

Why this give StackOverflowError? please check the sample code

```
public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Student st = new Student();
        st.setId(1);
        st.setName("Asus");
        st.setSurname("Corparation");
        System.out.println(st.toString());

    }

}

public class Student {

    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty surname;
    private IntegerProperty id;

    public IntegerProperty idProperty(){
        if(id == null){
            id= new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id");
        }
        return id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return idProperty().get();             
    }

    public void setId(int stdId){
        idProperty().set(stdId);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty(){
        if(name == null){
            name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public void setName(String stdName){
        nameProperty().set(stdName);
    }

    public StringProperty surnameProperty(){
        if(name == null){
            name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "surame");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname(){
        return surnameProperty().get();
    }

    public void setSurname(String stdSurname){
        nameProperty().set(stdSurname);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }


}
```

can **this** cause this problem? When I debug the code the class **IntegerPropertyBase.java** always return back my **toString** method when append **bean** and so that the infinite recursion cause this error in my opinion.

Comment: Can you try with `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + getName()+ ", surname=" + getSurname()+ ", id=" + getId()+ '}';
    }`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `toString` of a property it returns a debug string which includes information about the property owner. This in turn calls `toString` of the owner and you get a infinite recursion.

Therefore it does not make sense to call `toString` of a property in the `toString` method of the owner.

You can solve this by writing `Student.toString` as

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" + "name=" + getName() + ", surname=" + getSurname() + ", id=" + getId() + '}';
}
```

(But you need to instantiate surname).